# Accessing the Wikipedia Infobox image using python Wikipedia API

Tags: python-2.7, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, infobox

I want to access the Wikipedia infobox image for a given article title in a python program.Can someone please tell me how do I get that?

The following snipped gives list of all images in the page.I want to access just the infobox image.How do I do that?

```
import wikipedia
ny=wikipedia.page("Sachin Tendulkar")
print ny.images
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are using [wikipedia.py](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia), the Python API wrapper (the example you make is from the documentation).

Actually, the docs say exactly what you need: you have to check if the picture in the infobox is the *first* one (or second, third, etc.) one (I would say it is often, if not always, the first).

```
print ny.images[0]
```